# When a thread is done in jmeter does it clears out all the memory it has used?

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

When a thread is done in jmeter does it clears out all the memory it has used? Because I read some discussions where people are saying jmeter only releases memory after the test is done and suggest to use.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; 

JMeterVariables clean = new JMeterVariables(); 
vars = clean;
```

or simply

```
vars.remove(varName);
```

for every variable. Is it true? If yes then what is the best way to free the memory used by the threads?

Comment: by setting vars = clean, you are invoking java's automatic garbage clean up on the old object vars had a reference too.

Comment: i prefer to set my objects to null instead of a new object

Comment: So are you suggesting thread memory remains till the test lasts?

Comment: based on java, and your examples i'd say no. if you don't set vars = null or vars = clean (a brand new empty object of type JMeterVariables) then the memory referenced by vars will be whatever was created by the threads. If you know you are done with the JMeterVariables object after a test and want to reuse it for the next test then you could simply do vars = new JMeterVariables(). This will force garbage collection on the previous memory referenced by your vars object.

Answer (score 1):

When a Thread is really done in JMeter, JMeterVariables will be dropped, so you don't need to do this cleanup.

**BUT** during a load test, usually a Thread does a lot of iterations, in this case if you store a lot of variables, they will remain unless you override them in next iteration.

So it can be useful (only if you store big variables) to make some cleanup.

But this is useless:

```
JMeterVariables clean = new JMeterVariables(); 
vars = clean;
```

This is ok:

> vars.remove(varName);